How can I flatten gaps in Hardie siding planks?
My house was built with James Hardie siding planks and I noticed that some of them are not laying perfectly flat on the others, leaving a small gap in between. Not a big deal but I've seen bugs use the opening to enter (and prob hide) into the walls of the house (mainly ants and earwigs). I'm wondering if there's an easy fix for that (i.e. without removing/replacing everything). Can I nail them down? (I don't see any nail on any of the planks currently and I'm not sure if it's going to damage them or be too visible.)
Photos of two examples (note that the planks are not painted and I don't intend to paint them):



Welcome. Please take the [tour] so you know how to use this site.


"Perfectly flat" is not a reasonable goal for any siding.

Siding isn't intended to prevent pest ingress. That's the job of house wrap, sheathing, etc.

You have top-nailed siding with specific fastening requirements. While you can add nails to fix perceived issues, this degrades the longevity of the product and its appearance.



Pinning the plank down at the bottom edge is a common practice called “pin back.” It is used to correct “high nailing”, loose planks, gaps or rattling. Pinning of the butt joints is not intended to increase wind load values; and shall be installed 3/8 in. from end and between 3/4 in. and 1 in. from bottom edge. The finish nail shall be nailed fl ush to the surface (not countersunk), must be corrosion resistant (e.g. galvanized or stainless) and does not provide structural support. For best aesthetics nail heads should be touched-up to color match.
https://www.jameshardie.ca/jameshardiemainsite/media/site-documents/technicalbulletins/17-fastening-tips-for-hardieplank-lap-siding.pdf


Thanks a lot, so if you were me, you would leave the planks as is?

That one by the window is fairly severe, but I don't have a view of the front so I don't have specific advice.

Here's a photo / video of the front (for one of them): https://imgur.com/a/xG7z2Vo I'm tempted to use finish on the boards that have big gaps like the one on the photo:

All information belongs in your question post, not down here.
